# How to get comments that contains curly brackets ({}) in Reddit with PRAW?

Tags: python, praw

I'm trying to detect comments that use {} for a bot that I'm developing. What I want is the script to find all comments that use curly brackets and get the string in between those brackets. So, for example, if a comment says {dog}, I want to access 'dog'. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

What about using this regular expression to capture text within curly brackets `\{([^}]*)\}`?
Then you can use it like so in your Python code:

```
import re

regex = r"\{([^}]*)\}"
test_str = "The {dog} is {barking} in the {yard}."
matches = re.findall(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

print(matches)
# ['dog', 'barking', 'yard']
```